# Java: Convert signed Int_32 (hex) to Int

Tags: java, string, hex, type-conversion

I've got a signed int_32 value (FFFFFFFC) what's representing -4

If I try to convert it by ...

```
long x = Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFC", 32);
System.out.println("X: " + x);
```

... I'll get "X: 532021755372" instead of -4.
How could I convert it as a signed value?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "how to parse hex in Java". OP made several mistakes in his code that need to be fixed. Also, the solution is going to be different than any solution discussed in the previously mentioned duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an incorrect result because 32 represents the [numeric base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), not the number of bits in the result. You are parsing the string as a base-32 number (i.e. a number in a numbering system that uses digits 0..9 and letters A..V, not 0..9 and A..F.

To parse the number correctly, use `Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFC", 16);`, and cast the result to `int`, which is a 32-bit number:

```
int x = (int)Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFC", 16);
System.out.println("X: " + x); // Prints X: -4
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/fBHkFI)

Answer (score 2):

if FFFFFFFC represents -4 it is int, not long, parse it like this

```
int x = Integer.parseUnsignedInt("FFFFFFFC", 16);
```

and you will get -4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int x= new BigInteger("FFFFFFFC", 16).intValue();
System.out.println("X: " + x);
```